# How to match alphanumeric pattern in Regex?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, boost-regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Hi I am new to the regex I am trying to match the pattern for bellow line

```
T071108452T    42D896D5O 3587
```

I want to match the pattern till T071108452T    42D896D5 and after this i want the Character "O" to match i tried something like this

```
 (T)(\d{9})(T)(\d{0,19}\s{0,19}\w{0,19})O
```

but it contains the "O" already with the \w{0,19}  and i want to match "O" as specific character any help will be great thanks .

As for the more values are

```
T065000090T203 93 5797 9O 4037  
T325170628T0108626004D18O01054
T071108452T    42D896D5O 3587
```

So i want to match "T"-- then 9 digits then -- "T" and then any combination that is alphanumeric till --"O"

Comment: Is `42D896D5` always of the same maximum length? If so you can use `\w{0,8}(\w)` to match the last `O` in your example as a group.

Comment: I'm not sure your question is very clear. Do you have more examples of patterns to match and to reject?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to match? `(\d{0,19}\s{0,19}\w{0,19})` matches 0-19 digits followed by 0-19 spaces followed by 0-19 word characters. I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: The first `\d{0,19)` in your example does nothing -- at least, not for your example. The `\s{0,19}` seems redundant -- are you *expecting* zero, up to 19 spaces? One would suggest `\s+` here -- one space or more. Finally, to make your last `\w{0,19}` *non*-greedy, use `\w{0,19}?` instead. (In addition: what's with the random list of tags? You simply added everything related to regex you could find?)

Comment: I want to match the spaces,numbers and alphabets except "O" in the given pattern .. I am adding more values to get the pattern

Comment: @user2553512 This is how your current regex is working: [link](http://www.regex101.com/r/mQ1vN6). The first one does not match because of the spaces between the alphanumeric characters. But as far as I see, your regex is working as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have the following string:

```
  T071108452T    42D896D5O 3587O
Note that I added an extra O --^
```

If you want to match until the last `O`, you may use the following [pattern](http://regex101.com/r/rD5yS8): `[\w\s]+(?=O)`

This means:

- `[\w\s]+` match words and whitespaces one or more times, greedy.
- `(?=O)` Zerowidth lookahead assertion to match until `O` found

Now if you want to match until the first occurence of `O` then you may use the following [pattern](http://regex101.com/r/bA9jG0): `[\w\s]+?(?=O)`. Note the added question mark, it's to match ungreedy.

**Note:** `\w` will also match an underscore, you may replace `[\w\s]` by `[^\W\S_]` to prevent that. Note the negation and the uppercased letters.